# How to Stretch Multiple DIVs to Same Width After One DIV Pushes Another to Next Line

Tags: html, css

I have a ul list.  Each li item has 2 divs in it.  The second div is a fixed 200px while the first div should stretch to fill the remaining space, with a min-width of 200px.  I am trying to make it so if the browser is too small to fit both divs side by side, it will push the second div to a new line and the first div should stretch to the full width of the li.  In addition, If this happens to one li, it needs to happen on all the other li as well.

This is what I have for my html and CSS - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgoru8w0/2/)

```css
    .container {
        width: 50%;
        color: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    ul li {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .left {
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 200px;
        width: auto;
        background-color: blue;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        flex: 1 1 auto; /* dynamic width */
    }

    .right {
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 200px;
        background-color: red;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        flex: 0 0 auto;  /* fixed width */
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="container">
       <li>
         <div class="left">li 1: Some Text</div>
         <div class="right">Static Width</div>
       </li>
       <li>
         <div class="left">li 2: Some Pretty Long Text, Longer Than Others, so be ready to push red div to next line!</div>
         <div class="right">Static Width</div>
       </li>
       <li>
         <div class="left">li 3: Some More Text</div>
         <div class="right">Static Width</div>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

If you shrink the display area in the JSFiddle linked above, you can see li 2 text will start wrapping in the blue div.  Once it's shrunk to the point where the blue div hits its min-width of 200px, it adds a scrollbar for overflow.
I would like to make it so the red div will be pushed to the next line below the blue div if the blue div hits its min-width of 200px so the scrollbar will never appear and it will always fully display both blue and red divs.

In addition, if the pushing of the red div to the next line happens to one list item, I would like it to happen on the other items in the list as well.

Is this doable with only CSS?

Comment: you want the red div to wrap? its already doing that

Comment: in the fiddle you have not added `flex-wrap: wrap;`

Comment: @UmairFarooq Yes, however with the way it currently is, if you shrink the display area to < 400px, instead of pushing the red div to the next line, it just displays a horizontal scrollbar and keeps both divs on the same line.

Comment: they are on top of eachother? https://imgur.com/a/fb2jAYr